# How can I begin a new page inside the environment codebox?

Tags: environments, clrscode3e

If I write all codes inside one `codebox`, it will overfill the page. And if I write it in two boxes, then the line counter will restart from 1.

How can I save the line counter?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) see section 6 page 5 of [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clrscode3e) `We typeset pseudocode by putting it in a codebox environment. A codebox is a section of code that does
not break across pages.`

Comment: you can try  [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) or [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

Comment: @touhami: `codebox` is more of `algorithm` like stuff, so `listings` etc. does not provide the correct commands to display algorithms (but they break across pages).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you're right

Comment: @touhami: I provided an 'automatic' workaround

Comment: One should mention, that `codebox` is contained in the `clrscode3e` package (a strange name, in my point of view)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a preliminary version to maintain the line number at least for manual breaks, using `\codeboxcontinuedtrue` and `\codeboxcontinuedfalse`

The last line number is always stored at the end of a `codebox` and may be reinjected to the `codelinenumber` counter if `\ifcodeboxcontinued` evaluates to be `true`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clrscode3e}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{lastcodelinenumber}

\newif\ifcodeboxcontinued


\xapptocmd{\endcodebox}{%
  \setcounter{lastcodelinenumber}{\value{codelinenumber}}%
  \global\codeboxcontinuedfalse
}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\codebox}{%
  \ifcodeboxcontinued
  \setcounter{codelinenumber}{\value{lastcodelinenumber}}%
  \fi
}{}{}
\newcommand\continuecodebox{\global\codeboxcontinuedtrue}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li     \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li         \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence
$A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
\li         $i \gets j-1$
\li         \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li             \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li                 $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li         $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\end{codebox}
\clearpage % a manual break that would be necessary

\continuecodebox
\begin{codebox}
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li     \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li         \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence
$A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
\li         $i \gets j-1$
\li         \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li             \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li                 $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li         $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li     \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li         \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence
$A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
\li         $i \gets j-1$
\li         \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li             \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li                 $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li         $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li     \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li         \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence
$A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
\li         $i \gets j-1$
\li         \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li             \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li                 $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li         $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\end{codebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of improving your code: this way the numbering will only continue if `\continuecodebox` is issued, otherwise it restarts at the next `codebox` environment.

Comment: @egreg: Well, assuming, that there are no boxes that should break over three pages this is nice addition. Thanks.

Comment: One just adds `\continuecodebox` in front of any environment that should continue the numbering.

Comment: @egreg: I know.